# Integral of Algebraic Function (combination of cubic and quadratic)

Tags: integration

The Question :

$\int \frac{x^2+1}{x^3+x^2+1}dx$

What I tried :

1. Proceeded with partial Fraction but there is no obvious root of the denominator : $x^3+x^2+1$
2. Tried with Substitution but there is no obvious substitutions to perform or becomes a Second complicated Integral.
3. One method may be Finding the root of the denominator by Newton Approx. Method and then applying partial Fraction . . . .

Or Am I missing Anything ?

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition is the way to go. I don't really see another way. There is a formula for roots of a 3rd degree polynomial if needed.

Comment: @VincentBatens Yeah I obviously can do that but the the root is the Just feverishly long and complicated as well . . . I am in search of any simpler way around

Comment: Where did you get this integral? Did you just make it up or did you find it somewhere